# How do I create a system message for a user's first failed login attempt?

Tags: 7, users

When using the core login block on the homepage, it appears that the failed login system message, "Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?" is only presented to users on their second failed login attempt. The first time they fail, only the missing/incorrect username and/or password fields are highlighted. Is there any way of changing this default behaviour, so the system message is displayed on the first attempt, as well?

Comment: using stringoverride module you can safely change this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are always created when a user tries to login.

If the error message doesn't show, you must have a custom module, that removes the messages some how. Maybe via redirection or something similar.

Comment: I think you are correct. It appears that because I have the login block in a quicktab, the first login failure does not display the message. Disabling the block in a quicktab returns this message. Thank you.